# How to pass data from one class to another, when Bundle can't be used?

Tags: android, variables, android-intent

I have two Classes. Class A is an Activity that has integer variables that need to be used in Class B (not an Activity). I have been able to use Bundles to transfer data of variables from one Activity to another Activity before. The problem is that this time, Class B is not an Activity and extends ImageView so that the draw() function can be used. Because of this, I am unable to use normal Activity functions, such as Bundle-Intents or SharedPreferences to transfer data in primitive variables from Class A to my Class B. I receive an error saying that "getIntent() is undefined for type".

So my question is, how can Class B use the variables in Class A if I am unable to bundle? Is there another way?

Someone said they did not understand my question so hopefully the below example will help demonstrate better.

```
public Class1 extends Activity {

//so Class1 has some primitive data, and is an Activity w/layout

int var1;
int var2;
Bitmap bitmap;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.view);
}
}
```

A different class needs to draw onto canvas, but also needs to use the
information in var1 and var2 to be able to draw properly. But how to obtain that information?

```
   public Class2 extends ImageView {

    /*I am unable to use normal Activity functions, so I 
     *cannot onCreate, for example. I also cannot bundle, 
     *getIntent(), or use getSharedPreferences(). So how do I get var1 
     *and var2 value? */

    }
```

Update: I was able to get this to work using getters. I attempted this before, but it was not returning the correct values. If anyone else ever gets stuck with this similar issue, remember to setup your variables with "static". I'm still learning all the differences, but without static my getter was not working. Once I added static to my variables, everything worked out. So that's one observational tip (even without fully understanding the logic as to why). Thank you to all the responders for your tips.

Comment: Maybe it's worded poorly, but how do you manage to "extend ImageView" into an Activity? As is, that statement makes no sense to me.

Comment: Class A extends Activity, Class B extends ImageView. getIntent() and getSharedPreferences() are undefined for extending ImageView. So any attempts to Bundle of use sharedPreferences to pass primitive data seems impossible. I am asking if anyone knows the work around. Sorry for not being clear, hopefully it is now.

Comment: If you're extending your `ImageView`, then simply pass the data to the `Activity`, and provide getters and setters in your `ImageView` extension. This is the normal java pattern. And don't use `SharedPreferences` as some have suggested. That sort of access does not belong into a `View`.

Comment: why don't you use `sharedPreferences`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in different way.
First of all you can use static variable to do this. Such that you can declare a variable in class A `public static String variable;` and from class B you can get the value of this variable like this way `ClassA.variable`. 
Another way you can use by passing a context of class A to B and then use `SharedPreference`. 
Or create a new class which extends android Application. From class A you can set different variable value in application class. 
Now you can retreive those values from Application class. Hope this can help you.

Some code Sample using static variable

```
public Class1 extends Activity {
public static int var1 =20;
public static int var2 = 30;
}
```

Now get the variable value from class two

```
public Class2 extends ImageView {
Class1.var1;
Class.var2;
}
```

Second way using getter.

```
public Class1 extends Activity{
    int var1 =10;
    int var2 =20;


    public int getVar1() {
        return var1;
    }   
    public int getVar2() {
        return var2;
    }
}
```

Now you can get the variable value in Class2

```
public Class2 extends ImageView {
Class1 class1= new Class1();
class1.getVar1;
class1.getVar2; 
}
```

Also you can use `SharedPreference`. Hope it can help you. Thanks.

Comment: This worked perfect, the getter method. The first example not so much. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Various options exist:

1. The `Activity` can pass the information to `Class B`:

   ```
   class B {
       public void tellMeInformat(int usefulNumber) {
           // Do something
       }
   }
   ```
2. Or, you can pass the Activity to the ImageView:

   ```
   class A {

       initiation {

            B mySpecialImageView = /* Set it upo */;
            B.setParentActivity(this);
       }
   }

   class B {
       private myA = null;

       public void setParentActiviy {
           myA = A;
       }

       private void doSomething {
           int usefulNumber = A.getUsefulNumbner();
           // Do something
       }
   }
   ```